# extract some characters with instr

Tags: plsql

in pl/sql 
I have these text:

```
${cat};${dog};
```

I would like to extract these:

```
${dog}
```

I'm trying with instr but allways shows me the last semicolon with these:

```
SELECT substr(field,instr(field,'$',1,2),instr(field,';',1,2)-1),...
```

Any help please

Comment: Do you need the second entry in the semi-colon delimited list, or specifically "${dog}"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function is defined as `substr(str, pos, len)`, so you have to subtract the positions in the 3rd argument  as `substr(str, pos1, pos2 - pos1)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you need, but I would code this:

```
select substr('${cat};${dog};'
             ,instr('${cat};${dog};',';',1,1)+1
             ,instr('${cat};${dog};',';',1,2)-instr('${cat};${dog};',';',1,1)-1
             )
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

If looking for the second item in the list, here's a way using REGEXP_SUBSTR() to return the 2nd occurrence of a set of zero or more characters that are not a semi-colon, where they are followed by a semi-colon or the end of the line.  This allows for a NULL value in the list:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('${cat};${dog};', '([^;]*)(;|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) from dual;
```

Even better, make the call to REGEXP_SUBSTR generic and put it into a stored function that you pass a string, the element you want and the delimiter and have it return the string.

Benefits:

```
-   Logic and code is encapsulated in a reusable function all can use without having to understand the regular expression syntax (but still get the power from it)
-   There is a consistent, simple way to call it
-   Code becomes MUCH easier to follow/debug
-   If it needs to change there is only one place to change it
-   A particular element of a list can be SELECTed
-   An element of a list can be used in a WHERE clause
```

Here is the function definition itself:

```
  FUNCTION  GET_LIST_ELEMENT(string_in VARCHAR2, element_in NUMBER, delimiter_in VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',') RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEGIN
      RETURN REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_in, '([^\'||delimiter_in || ']*)(\'||delimiter_in||'|$)', 1, element_in, NULL, 1);
  END GET_LIST_ELEMENT;
```